# Limit of $\frac{\cos(x)}{e^x-1}$

Tags: calculus, limits

I have the task to compute the following limit: $$\lim_{x\to -\infty}f(x),$$
where $f(x)=\frac{\cos(x)}{e^x-1}.$ I know the limit is indeterminate, but I am unsure whether my "proof" is correct.

Let us take two sequences $x_n'=-2n\pi$ and $x_n''=-(2n+1)\pi$. For both of them, the limit is equal to minus infinity as n goes to infinity. Now, let us consider two limits: $\lim_{n\to +\infty}f(x_n')$ and $\lim_{n\to +\infty}f(x_n'')$, and show they are unequal.

So, we have:

$\lim_{n\to +\infty}f(x_n')=\lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{\cos(-2n\pi)}{e^{-2n\pi}-1}=\lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{1}{e^{-2n\pi}-1}=-1$

and

$\lim_{n\to +\infty}f(x_n'')=\lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{\cos(-2(n+1)\pi)}{e^{-2n\pi}-1}=\lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{-1}{e^{-2n\pi}-1}=1$

since $\lim_{n\to +\infty}{e^{-2n\pi}}=0$.

Therefore the limit of $f(x)$ is indeterminate.
Is it correct?

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: [Wolfram-Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=limit%5Bcos%28x%29%2F%28e%5Ex-1%29%2Cx-%3Einf%5D) says something different, but it wasn't the first time it gives some mistaken results, so I don't know.

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=limit%5Bcos%28x%29%2F%28e%5Ex-1%29%2Cx-%3E-inf%5D, look here.

Comment: I've never used Wolfram-Alpha but have noticed that with limits involving infinity or indeterminate forms that people report odd results.  In this case intuition shows the numerator is oscillating as the denominator goes to -1 and your analysis shows that. I would say this is DNE not indeterminate.

Comment: Wolfram-Alpha is correct here. @Joako used + infinity instead of - infinity in the limit.